# How to use ftruncate in c99 without warning

Tags: c, c99

I want to use ftruncate function in my code. I have to compile with option std=c99. I get warning:

```
In function ‘test’:
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ftruncate’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I tied to find on the Internet any solution which can solve this problem but I don't succeeded in.

I use ftrucnate because I want to clear content of an opened file after I get lock (flock).

Comment: Could you please show a part of your actually code? And did you include all required header files?

Comment: Did you include `#include <unistd.h>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `ftruncate()` isn't a standard C function, and you've asked for standards enforcement, you need to define the appropriate feature test macros (see `feature_test_macros(7)`).

From the `ftruncate(2)` manpage:

> ```
>    ftruncate():
>        _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
>        _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
>        || /* Since glibc 2.3.5: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
> ```

In other words, to expose the `ftruncate()` function you must define one of these macros, for example:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 myfile.c
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting this error even with the constant set. Is there some other trick to be done? I'm running on Cygwin.

Comment: You could specify the function prototype before your main() function or in a header file:  int ftruncate(int fd, off_t length);

Answer (score 8):

FatalError's answer did not work for me. Mostly all you have to do for it to work is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```