# C++ compilation stuck with boost interprocess lib 'error: `::ftruncate' has not been declared'

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

This is what I get when I run `make` :

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp:25:0,
                 from init.cpp:61:
/usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp: In function `bool boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::truncate_file
(boost::interprocess::file_handle_t, std::size_t)':
/usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:489:16: error: `::ftruncate' has not been declared
    return 0 == ::ftruncate(hnd, off_t(size));
                ^~
init.cpp: In function `void registerSignalHandler(int, void (*)(int))':
init.cpp:302:22: error: aggregate `registerSignalHandler(int, void (*)(int))::sigaction sa' has incomplete type and cannot be
 defined
     struct sigaction sa;
                      ^~
init.cpp:304:28: error: `sigemptyset' was not declared in this scope
     sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
                            ^
init.cpp:306:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type `struct registerSignalHandler(int, void (*)(int))::sigaction'
     sigaction(signal, &sa, nullptr);
                                   ^
init.cpp:302:12: note: forward declaration of `struct registerSignalHandler(int, void (*)(int))::sigaction'
     struct sigaction sa;
            ^~~~~~~~~
```

I am on cygwin

`$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW abcd 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:41 i686 Cygwin`

I am not sure if all the build errors are related to the missing ::ftruncate, but I would like to start there.

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

TIA

**Update #1**:
/usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp does contain the required headers:

```
#if defined (BOOST_INTERPROCESS_WINDOWS)
#  include <boost/interprocess/detail/win32_api.hpp>
#else
#  ifdef BOOST_HAS_UNISTD_H
#     include <fcntl.h>
#     include <unistd.h>
#     include <sys/types.h>
#     include <sys/stat.h>
#     include <errno.h>
#     include <cstdio>
#     include <dirent.h>
#     if 0
#        include <sys/file.h>
#     endif
#  else
#    error Unknown platform
#  endif
#endif
```

**Update #2:** (using new CPPFLAG -> `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`)

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/size.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/as_literal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp:19,
                 from netbase.cpp:25:
netbase.cpp: In function `bool LookupIntern(const char*, std::vector<CNetAddr>&, unsigned int, bool)':
netbase.cpp:95:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             assert(aiTrav->ai_addrlen >= sizeof(sockaddr_in));
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
netbase.cpp:101:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             assert(aiTrav->ai_addrlen >= sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
netbase.cpp: In function `std::string NetworkErrorString(int)':
netbase.cpp:720:41: error: `strerror_r' was not declared in this scope
     if (strerror_r(err, buf, sizeof(buf)))
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got these errors under cygwin with my own CMake project because I attempted to build with `-std=c++11` and under cygwin that means that g++ will be strict and not include ftruncate or strdup. The solution was to either add `-std=gnu++11` or to set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)
```

The first line sets the CXX standard (the `-std` option for gcc), the second line prevents CMake from falling back to a lower standard (which you might not need) and the third line enables compiler specific extensions like `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11` for gcc. That variable is `ON` by default but I thought it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: Just encountered same problem because I was accidentally compiling with C++11. Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the header is missing some required includes. `man ftruncate` tells me that you need

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Try including these before including boost interprocess headers. If then still it fails to recognize these functions, clearly Cygwin does not support those functions.

Confer the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) documentation

Comment: Have you checked that adding the include before helps? I realize it could be a library header defect.

Comment: I was just typing my response but thought I would go ahead and update the OP :). Please see Update #1.

Comment: My question stands. It's worth the check. You really want to know whether you have a problem with Cygwin's POSIX features, or something related to boost. Different problems

Comment: I am going to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806764/how-to-use-ftruncate-in-c99-without-warning and see how it goes...... Will keep you posted.

Comment: I think I might need `newlib` since `glibc` is not available in cygwin. I am assuming that the "error: `strerror_r' was not declared in this scope" is related to that. Thoughts/suggestions ?